# insert cumulative values between non-existed dates:

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

Suppose Tom placed two orders on Monday and Friday. But I want to figure out an efficient way to insert no-purchase data for Tue,Wed,Thu, which are not existed in my data so I can calculate cumulative total spending for every day for Tom.

My current code is to create an massive user-date(full date,from 2010-2011); merge them with existed data by full merge; fill in missing value; calculate cumsum.

```
user<-c("Tom","Tom","Jim","Jim")
order_time<-c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-04", "2018-01-02","2018-01-04")
total_spending<-c(20,80,50,60)
dt<-data.frame(user,order_time,total_spending)

> dt
  user order_time total_spending
1  Tom 2018-01-01             20
2  Tom 2018-01-04             80
3  Jim 2018-01-02             50
4  Jim 2018-01-04             60
```

Desired output

```
user order_time total_spending cumulative_spending
1  Tom 2018-01-01             20                  20
2  Tom 2018-01-02              0                  20
3  Tom 2018-01-03              0                  20
4  Tom 2018-01-04             80                 100
5  Jim 2018-01-02             50                  50
6  Jim 2018-01-03              0                  50
7  Jim 2018-01-04             60                 110
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`complete`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html) with [`seq.Date`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/seq.Date.html):

```
dt %>% 
  mutate(order_time = as.Date(order_time)) %>%
  group_by(user) %>%
  complete(order_time =seq.Date(min(order_time), max(order_time), by="day")) %>%
  replace_na(list(total_spending = 0)) %>%
  mutate(cumulative_spending = cumsum(total_spending))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   user [2]
  user  order_time total_spending cumulative_spending
  <fct> <date>              <dbl>               <dbl>
1 Jim   2018-01-02            50.                 50.
2 Jim   2018-01-03             0.                 50.
3 Jim   2018-01-04            60.                110.
4 Tom   2018-01-01            20.                 20.
5 Tom   2018-01-02             0.                 20.
6 Tom   2018-01-03             0.                 20.
7 Tom   2018-01-04            80.                100.
```